# Appropriate method for clustering ordinal variables

Tags: cluster-analysis, spss, ordinal

I was reading through all (or most) previously asked questions, but couldn't find an answer to my problem...
I have 13 variables measured on an ordinal scale (thy represent knowledge transfer channels), which I want to cluster (HCA) for a following binary logistic regression analysis (including all 13 variables is not possible due to sample size of N=208). A Factor Analysis seems inappropriate due to the scale level. I am using SPSS (but tried R as well).

Questions:
1: Am I right in using the Chi-Squared measure for count data instead of the (squared) euclidian distance?
2. How can I justify a choice of method? I tried single, complete, Ward and average, but all give different results and I can't find a source to base my decision on.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1: Since the variables are on ordinal scale, the chi-square test is an appropriate measurement test. Because, "A Chi-square test is designed to analyze categorical data. That means that the data has been counted and divided into categories. It will not work with parametric or continuous data (such as height in inches)." [Reference](http://www.ling.upenn.edu/~clight/chisquared.htm).

Again, ordinal scaled data is essentially count or frequency data you can use regular parametric statistics: mean, standard deviation, etc Or non-parametric tests like `ANOVA` or `Mann-Whitney U test` to compare 2 groups or `Kruskal–Wallis H test` to compare three or more groups.

Answer 2: In a clustering problem, the choice of distance method solely depends upon the type of variables. I recommend you to read these detailed posts [1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3713/choosing-a-clustering-method), [2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80377/which-distance-to-use-e-g-manhattan-euclidean-bray-curtis-etc?noredirect=1&lq=1),[3](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/195456/how-to-select-a-clustering-method-how-to-validate-a-cluster-solution-to-warran?noredirect=1&lq=1)